# Logs in Kibana are not sorted by log timestamp

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack, filebeat

I use Filebeat and Logstash to send logs to Elasticsearch. I can see my logs in Kibana but logs are not sorted correctly according to the timestamp in log record.
I tried to create a separate field `dateTime` for the log record timestamp but it looks like it's not possible to sort table in Kibana by that column.

[Kibana screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wE3d.png)

Could anybody explain what could be a solution in this situation?

filebeat

```
filebeat.prospectors:
- input_type: log
  paths:
    - /var/log/app.log
  fields_under_root: true
  multiline.pattern: '^[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2},[0-9]{3}'
  multiline.negate: true
  multiline.match: after
registry_file: /var/lib/filebeat/registry

output.logstash:
  hosts: ["host_name:5044"]
  ssl.certificate_authorities: ["..."]
```

logstash

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
    ssl => true
    ssl_certificate => "..."
    ssl_key => "..."
  }
}

filter {
  if [type] == "filebeat" {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "(?<dateTime>[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2},[0-9]{3})"}
    }
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "elasticsearch:9200"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is exactly what [the `date` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-date.html) is made for. Add this after your grok expression:

```
date {
  match => [ "dateTime", "HH:mm:ss.SSS" ]
}
```

This will set the `@timestamp` field that Kibana sorts by to be the value in this field.

Comment: Thanks, but it didn’t overwrite `@timestamp` values, it just created field `dateTime` with actual log timestamp. 
Btw, how can I add month, day and year values to the actual log timestamp?